# Strip in Python until the last same blank char and remove a char in the end of the line

Tags: python, string, split, strip

I've an input like this (millions of lines)

```
1   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test0.png      output  [ 0.03921137 0.00651542]
2   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test1.png      output  [ 0.03896755 0.00643029]
3   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test2.png      output  [ 0.03919738 0.00645864]
4   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test3.png      output  [ 0.0392952 0.00693588]
...
```

and want this output

```
0.00651542
0.00643029
0.00645864
0.00693588
...
```

Need to strip until the last blank space and remove "]" before "\n" but I'm failing. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: split on whitespace, take the last column, rstrip the right-bracket?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by splitting, indexing, and slicing:

```
>>> x = '1   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test0.png      output  [ 0.03921137 0.00651542]'
>>> x.split()[-1][:-1]
'0.00651542'
```

Repeat as needed for each line.

The following is an amended program:

```
>>> def p(s):
...     x = s.split()
...     if x[-1] == ']': return x[-2]
...     return x[-1][:-1]
... 
>>> p('1   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test0.png      output  [ 0.03921137 0.00651542]')
'0.00651542'
>>> p('1   /home/ubuntu/test_images/test0.png      output  [ 0.03921137 0.00651542 ]')
'0.00651542'
```

The second string ends with `' ]'`.

Comment: There is a new problem =/ some lines have 1 more blank space before "]", like: "output [ 0.03811574 0.841492 ]". This is breaking my wished list...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to use `.rstrip()` to remove `\n` at the end of the lines, split the input on whitespace, get the last element (e.g. `0.0000]`) and then slice to remove the trailing `]`.

```
with open('test_txt.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip().split(" ")[-1][:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be slightly more efficient to `rsplit`. That way you don't create as many elements in each split list per iteration.

e.g.

Python 3

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        rest, end = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
        print(end[:-1])
```

Output:

```
0.00651542
0.00643029
0.00645864
0.00693588
```

For Python 2 it can be done like so

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        rest, end = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        print(end[:-1])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting: TypeError: rsplit() takes no keyword arguments